# Worst case time complexity of hashing (insertion)

Tags: algorithm, list, hash

If I use basic collision handling by having to relocate the input value to the next empty slot, wouldn't I need n*(n+1)/2 hits in total?

Example:

Input: 0,0,0;

Allocated size=3;

Thus it would require 6 hits in total to allocate all three values.

I've read that the worst case complexity is O(n) but shouldn't it be O(n^2) then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each insertion is O(1) in average (with a good hash function and resizing strategy), but O(N) in the worst case. So N insertions are O(N^2) in the worst case.

Comment: Had a brainfart, somehow equated 1 insertion with n insertions.

Answer (score 0):

It's `O(N)` on average.

It's indeed `O(N^2)` in the worst case.